# Mamp connect to a global sql database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, mamp, local

Im using mamp to create a local server and run my pho page.
I try since a couple of hours to connect to my sql database.
It's not the sql from mamp.
The sql is provided from my provider 1&1.
The reason is, i want to connect local from my home to the database , but also when I'm in my office, but both times with a local hostet PHP page.

Regards Tim

Comment: with 1&1 you cannot connect from your local system to the db hosted on 1&1 servers - they are firewalled specifically to prevent you doing that

Comment: So there is No way to host a local homepage , which one I just can open but connect to a global sql.

Comment: not as far as I know with 1&1. You could perhaps use a proxy type script running on your live site and connect via that proxy type script locally but that is theory only

Comment: Perhaps there is an other way. My plan is to built a PHP page for material statistics from the production. So if I use material A or material B or Material C it safe +1 for the material with dthe date in a sql database. So I can see how much material from each type I used every day / week ... and to make the chart I want to use google charts . But for google charts I think I'll need a internet based sql